# Bootstrap-Vue: @click.native on <b-form-checkbox> behaves weird

Tags: javascript, checkbox, bootstrap-4, vue.js

I have an issue with `b-form-checkbox` and `b-form-checkbox-group`. When I use `@click.native`, the method I call, is executed two times. Also, if I write my selected (array) values directly into the DOM `{{selected}}`, I see the correct elements in the array. However if I `console.log my` selected array in the method I call on `@click.native`, when clicking a checkbox, it is empty. When I then click the checkbox again (so it is unchecked), my `console.log` displays the element in my selected array.

```
{{selected}}

<b-form-checkbox-group
stacked
:options="options"
v-model="selected"
@click.native ="filterTable"
></b-form-checkbox-group>
```

And my filtertable is just a console.log

```
filterTable(){
   console.log(this.selected);
}
```

If I use @mouseup.native filterTable is only called one time. However the selected array behaves the same. In the DOM it shows correct, but in my method the selected array is inverted.

I created a fiddle for it. https://jsfiddle.net/y998pLya/5/

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You may use `@input` instead of `@click.native`
https://jsfiddle.net/y998pLya/7/

Comment: The only issue is that I need to stop propagation when clicking on the checkbox, because I place it inside the bootstrap-vue table header (th), which by default activates the sort functionality. Do you know how to add a stop propagation to @input?

Comment: This is probably solved already, but for anyone else having issues with this, I am using @change and this works fine.